# How do I draw a box around a venn diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I created this venn diagram, and I need to put a box around it as a border, how would I do that?

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, blend group=screen]
  \fill[lightgray] ( 290:.7) circle (1);
  \fill[gray] (150:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[darkgray] (25:.8) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `backgrounds` library provides a `framed` option which you can pass to your picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, blend group=screen, framed]
      \fill[lightgray] ( 290:.7) circle (1);
      \fill[gray] (150:.6) circle (1);
      \fill[darkgray] (25:.8) circle (1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: framed diagram]

You can alter the style by changing the `background rectangle` style. For example,

```
background rectangle/.style={ultra thick, rounded corners=5pt, draw}
```

produces

[image: slightly fancier framed diagram]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, blend group=screen]
  \fill[lightgray] ( 290:.7) circle (1);
  \fill[gray] (150:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[darkgray] (25:.8) circle (1);
  \draw[thick] ([shift={(-0.1,-0.1)}]current bounding box.south west) rectangle ([shift={(0.1,0.1)}]current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]